# how can i keep backend Data synced with frontend

Tags: java, spring, rect

I have a "user" class which contains a status attribute, I want to display this attribute in a dashboard.
when the backend changes this attribute I want the frondEnd to display the new value directly without reloading the page .
I use Spring and React

Comment: Hmm I think you should consider using a websocket.

Comment: can you explain to me how?

Comment: who is responsible for the backend update. The current user in front of his computer, or another user or thread somewhere else ?

Comment: yes it's another module that will change the status . it is not the user who uses the dashboard

Comment: so you need a websocket to push data from the server to the front-end. You have to set up a kind of notification system on your backend that emit data when something in particular has changed (like user.status). I don't have any pre-built solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pub-sub mechanism to achieve this. for example, a kafka topic can be used to sync your changes with the front end.
[image: sample data flow]

1. while inserting a record in your backend DB, push a message to user-kafka-topic.
2. add a user-kafka-consumer in your front-end application. It would consume messages from the user-kafka-topic at runtime.
3. you can plan to add you own front-end DB and update the front-end DB.
4. use observer pattern in your frontend to to update your UI as soon as your json data for the page changes.

Comment: Hi, @Rahul how to consume kafka topic at frontend side? Do you have any link to describe this?